# How do I change the date format Laravel outputs to JSON?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I've built an application in Laravel and eloquent returns dates in this format: `2015-04-17 00:00:00`. I'm sending one particular query to JSON so I can make a graph with D3, and I think I would like the dates in ISO8601 (`'1995-12-17T03:24:00'`) or some other format that plays nice with the javascript Date() constructor.

Is there a way to change the date format being output to JSON on the Laravel end? I'm not sure using a mutator is the best approach because it would affect the date in other parts of my application.

Or would it be better to leave the JSON output as is, and use some javascript string methods to manipulate the date format before passing it to the Date() constructor? Which approach is more efficient?

Here is my model:

```
class Issue extends Model {



protected $fillable = [
    'client_id',
    'do',
    'issue_advocate',
    'service_number',
    'issue_location',
    'issue_description',
    'level_of_service',
    'outcome',
    'referral_id',
    'file_stale_date',
    'date_closed',
    'issue_note',
    'staff_hours'
];

protected $dates = [
    'do',
    'date_closed',
    'file_stale_date'
];

public function setDoAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['do'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('F j, Y', $value)->toDateString();
}
}
```

Here is my query:

```
$issues = Issue::with('issuetypes')
->select(['do','level_of_service','outcome','id'])
->whereBetween('do',[$lastyear,$now])
->get()->toJson();
```

And the JSON I get back:

```
[{"do":"2014-12-23 00:00:00","level_of_service":1,"outcome":1,"id":18995,"issuetypes":[{"id":9,"issuetype":"Non Liberty","pivot":{"issue_id":18995,"issuetype_id":9}}]}]
```

Comment: You can parse a date in pretty much any format in D3.

Comment: Try to use mutators and accessors, read more about it from laravel doc's

Comment: With `d3` this is as easy as: `var format = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'); var myDate = format.parse('1995-12-17T03:24:00');`

Comment: As of version 7, the [laravel default date serialization format](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/12d339bfc7bae27f5507491a64ea2ca0a0add8fa) was changed

Answer (score 26):

I know it's an old question, but there is still no good answer to that.
Changing `protected $dateFormat` will affect database, instead method `serializeDate()` must be overriden

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date) {
        return $date->getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

Or myself I chose to create trait

```
trait UnixTimestampSerializable
{
    protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

and then add

```
class SomeClassWithDates extends Model {    
    use UnixTimestampSerializable;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Agreed. The main problem is that overriding `$dateFormat`  will have an effect on both input and output, whereas the question is about formatting output only.

Comment: Just to make this answer complete... The first snippet does not work due to the DateTime in the method signature. The trait works perfect, but will not return a ISO8601. To do that you can use `return $date->format('c);`

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on [umbrel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41569026/4149914) a bit I've created a trait that turns the DateTimeInstance into a [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) instance so that I can easily make use of it's [common formats](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats).

In my particular case I wanted to serialize all dates according to ISO-8601.

The trait is as follows...

```
use DateTimeInterface;
use Carbon\Carbon;

trait Iso8601Serialization
{
    /**
     * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
     *
     * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
     * @return string
     */
    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return Carbon::instance($date)->toIso8601String();
    }

}
```

and from here I can simply use it on the relevant models...

```
class ApiObject extends Model
{
    use Iso8601Serialization;
}
```

Obviously you could name the trait more appropriately if you're using a different format but the point is that you can use any of Carbon's common formats simply by replacing `toIso8601String()` with the format you need.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you use the Carbon class to handle all your dates and datetimes variables, it already comes with Laravel 5 so you can start using whenever you want.

Check it out on [Carbon Repo](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) to see what you can do with it.

As an example, you can format dates from your model like this

```
Carbon::parse($model->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')
```

As for a good approach, I would suggest to use the [Repository Pattern](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository) along with Presenters and Transformers. By using it you can define how you want your json to be displayed/mounted and opt to skip the presenter whenever you want in order to still get you Eloquent model returned when you make your queries.

Comment: I am using carbon. I guess there is no way built in to Laravel to only affect the JSON output? I'm a fairly new developer and I feel like the Repository Pattern might be too complex for me.

Answer (score 2):

use this function in any **Model**

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date){
    return $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
}
```

> Result

[image]

Comment: Extra point for Laravel 9 users, you have to use `\DateTimeInterface'

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal I have tried overriding the serializeDate method in a trait, in an intermediary parent class between Model and my model class (Issue extends TimestampOverride extends Model), I defined the function as protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date) in Laravel 9 but my created_at date is always returned in UTC. Please advise! DB has EST timezone, app/config.php has timezone: 'America/New_York'. Timetamps are stored in the DB in EST, but Eloquent Model queries return UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the format that used to convert date/time to string when your models are serialized as JSON by setting **$dateFormat** property of your model to the format you need, e.g.:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
  protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
}
```

You can find docs on different placeholders you can use in the format string here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Also, let your model know which fields are dates using `protected $dates = ['my_date_field', 'updated_at', 'disabled_at'];` This will make those fields return a Carbon instance by default, and will format them according to $dateFormat when you dump them to JSON.

Comment: I am using `protected $dates`. I don't think `protected $dateFormat ='U';` is going to work for me because it looks like that will affect what is going to the database. When I experiment with it, it doesn't seem to affect the JSON output either. Maybe I am doing it wrong? I will edit my post to include code.

Comment: It should work, have a look at Eloquent Model's class method serializeDate(): https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.1/Eloquent/Model.php#L2969 this is what is used when you serialize a model object to json. just make sure that the all date fields are included in $dates property

Comment: It's not working, its giving an error InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Trailing data even after I include the $dates field

Comment: It happens to me, did you find something to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use usuals techniques as

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
```

or

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date) { ... }
```

or

```
protected $casts = [ "myDate" => "date:Y-m-d" ];
```

It'll only works when laravel will serialize itself objects. And you will anyway to put those code inside all models, for all properties.

So my solution, you have to (too) put this code in all models for all date properties by at last, it works in ALL cases :

```
public function getMyDateAttribute()
{
    return substr($this->attributes['my_date'], 0, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case for anyone with similar issues (in Laravel 9): timestamps in the DB are stored in EST (not UTC) timezone (don't ask me why, it's a legacy decision). I need all DB queries to write and read timestamps in EST. In `config/app.php` I have `'timezone' => 'America/New_York'`. This takes care of writing in EST. For reading I need the following below.

Overriding the `protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date)` only affects Eloquent Model queries serialized with toArray() or toJson() like below:

```
    $serializedModelRequest = MyModel::where('some_field', 'some_value')
        ->select('created_at')
        ->first()
        ->toArray();
```

If you want both the Eloquent Model query and the serialized queries return timestamps in the timezone stored in the DB you need to override the `protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date)` and add accessors to the timestamp fields. You can add these methods in a parent class, a trait or directly to your model. In the example here I used a trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait DbTimestamp
{
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

My model will use the the trait:

```
use App\Traits\DbTimestamp;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use DbTimestamp;
...
```

Now all three requests will return timestamps in EST timezone:

```
$serializedModelRequest = MyModel::where('some_field', 'some_value')
    ->select('created_at')
    ->first()
    ->toArray();

$eloquentModelRequest = MyModel::where('some_field', 'some_value')
    ->select('created_at')
    ->first();

$queryRequest = DB::table('my_model_table')
    ->where('some_field', '=', 'some_value')
    ->select('created_at')
    ->first();

$response->serialized_created_at = $serializedModelRequest['created_at'];
$response->eloquent_created_at = $eloquentModelRequest->created_at;
$response->query_created_at = $queryRequest->created_at;
```