# Laravel - formatting all dates simultaneously

Tags: laravel, datetime, model, attributes

I'm currently working on a POC to showcase that it's going to be fairly painless to create an API with Laravel, the catch being that the database is already set in stone.

One problem I've run into is that they've used custom created at and updated at column names, e.g. for a `car` table, the created_at column would be `car_time` and the updated date would be `cardata_time`, and these are all saved as unix timestamps.

I know you can set the CREATED_AT and UPDATED_AT columns for each model. I want to go another step and return all dates in ISO 8601 format.

I've inserted a class between my models and `Model` called `MasterModel` and I want to do something like

```
protected function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
    $datetime = new DateTime($value);
    return $datetime->format($format);
}
```

to make all created at dates be in that format. The problem is that I the custom created at and updated columns mean that this never gets called.

Is there a way for me to identify the created at and updated at columns in such a way that I can use a single method to updated all created at dates at the same time?

---

UPDATE: I realize my original question was not clear enough - I need to identify all fields that are dates, not just created_at and updated_at, and have them formatted a certain way. They will always be unix timestamps. Not sure how I'd go about this.

Comment: Do you want the ISO format only when you get a JSON representation of a Model?

Comment: To be buntly clear, add an example of the result you expect to get and what you're currently getting

Comment: I think what you are referring to is in here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization. Basically @Skytigger answer

Comment: @MohamedAllal Carbon::serializeUsing() as recommended in the docs is not working, see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21703 This question has some interesting answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074356/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-laravel-outputs-to-json/41569026#41569026

Comment: @Skytiger Well have you tried it ? In the thread they fixed it. However i think that the overriding of serializeDate in the model is better. Using a trait will make it simple. You have your answer. thank you too. And please tell me if you tried carbon way. And if you have last laravel version. Thank you

Comment: @Skytiger i also updated my answer to include the above !

Comment: I am using laravel 5.5.something - I've stopped work on this because the time I had to do it ran out, I have a rough PoC though, and was able to answer most of the questions I was asked during my presentation thanks to you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Here an answer that will expand on @caddy dz answer who happen to be sitting with me.

## All the things that need to be known

### Deactivation of auto management of timestamps

```php
public $timestamps = false; // <-- deactivate the automatic handling
```

### Change table attributes names

```php
const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date'; // <--- change the names
const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
```

source doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

> By default, Eloquent expects **created_at** and **updated_at** columns to
>   exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns
>   automatically managed by Eloquent, set the **$timestamps** property on
>   your model to false:

### Creating the accessors

```php
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        // do whatever you want here  (change and mutate the value)
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

- First thing to know, is that the accessors are a global concept for
  eloquent and can be writing for all attributes and not just
  `getCreatedAtAttribute` or `getUpdatedAtAttribute`.
- Second thing to know is that whatever the name of the column, that is
  in **camle case (firstName)** or **with _ (first_name)** eloquent know to
  match to it. The format of the accessor should be
  `get[NameOfATtribute]Attribute` in **pascal case** (camle case but first
  letter too in uppercase).
- Three the method argument hold the **value** of the **column** in
  question. Bellow a snippet that show how it's used

```php
$user = App\User::find(1);

$firstName = $user->first_name; //|=> first_name => getFirstNameAttribute(columnVal)
```

The resolution is clear.

> first_name  (column name) => **getFirstNameAttribute**(columnValue)

All the snippets are from the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

## Let's apply all of that

First we need to not use `$table->timestamps()` in the migration so we make the changment to the bellow.

```php
Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->timestamp('cardata_time', 0)->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('car_time', 0)->nullable();
});
```

Then we apply the modification on our model: 
 - we deactivate the auto handling of  timestamps. 
 - Override the timestamps columns names. 
 - And create the accessors.

Here depend on what we want. If we want to only do the above here a snippet that show that:

```php
// deactivate auto timestamps management
public $timestamps = false;

// change the columns names     
const CREATED_AT = 'car_time';
const UPDATED_AT = 'cardata_time';

// creating the accessors (respect the naming)

protected function getCarTimeAttribute($value) //car_time => CarTime
{
    // <-- do whatever you want here (example bellow)

    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
    $datetime = new DateTime($value);
    return $datetime->format($format);
}

protected function getCardataTimeAttribute($value) //cardata_time => CardataTime
{
    // <-- do whatever you want here

    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
    $datetime = new DateTime($value);
    return $datetime->format($format);
}
```

## Doing it with renaming the attributes completely

If what you want is to use another accessing name. Then what my friend @caddy dz did is the way to go. Which happen to be sitting with me. And dared me to expand upon the answer. (hhhh)

You will need to know

### $appends and $hidden

Part of the serialization API.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

> `$appends` allow us to add attributes to the model. That don't exists on the table. We need also to create an **accessors** for them.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['is_admin'];

    // ........

    /**
     * Get the administrator flag for the user.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsAdminAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['admin'] == 'yes';
    }
}
```

and

> `$hidden` allow us to remove and limit the attribute from the models. Like with the password field.

Doc examples:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

And from that what we need to do is to hide the attributes holding the time, that want to be changed to somehting else.

```php
// remove the old attributes names
protected $hidden = ['car_time', 'cardata_time']; // renaming those 
// append the new one   \/                  \/    <- to those   
protected $appends = ['car_crated_at', 'cardata_created_at']; // names just for illustration

protected function getCarCreatedAtAttribute($value) // car_created_at => CarCreatedAt
{
    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
    $datetime = new DateTime($value);
    return $datetime->format($format);
}

protected function getCardataCreatedAtAttribute($value) // cardata_created_at => CardataCreatedAt
{
    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
    $datetime = new DateTime($value);
    return $datetime->format($format);
}
```

## Applying it for different models

The basic idea is to create a base model then extend it when you create your model.

## Formatting all time attributes of the model without exception

If what you want is to apply the formatting for all the time attributes within the model.

Then override `serializeDate()` method. In practice write a trait, and then you can apply it. Otherwise a base model.

The answer bellow cover it well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41569026/7668448

And historically This thread is interesting :

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21703

### Serializing in Carbon level

In the documentation laravel 5.7 and up (what i checked [doc only]) :
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization

We can change the formatting at the level of carbon serialization. But it happen that there was **a bug in the past**. Normally fixed but i didn't try it. Bug was in 5.7 and fixed in 5.7 if i'm not wrong. The git link above discuss it.

Snippet:

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Carbon::serializeUsing(function ($carbon) {
            return $carbon->format('U');
        });
    }
```

___THE_END ^ ^

Comment: Thank you, the two of you definitely cleared up some questions for me!

Comment: @Skytiger Glade to hear that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking but if you have `cardata_time` and `car_time` in your table defined like this

```php
Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->bigIncrements('id');
     $table->timestamp('cardata_time', 0)->nullable();
     $table->timestamp('car_time', 0)->nullable();
});
```

And a MasterModel like so

```php
/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;

const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['car_time', 'cardata_time'];

protected function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
    $datetime = new DateTime($value);
    return $datetime->format($format);
}

protected function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
    $datetime = new DateTime($value);
    return $datetime->format($format);
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "created_at": "2019-09-02T20:31:38Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-09-02T20:31:38Z"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have to put down that much boilerplate every time I create a new class, I want to be able to register an attribute as a date and have it formatted. This would potentially cover other date fields as well, not sure created at and updated at. Thanks though.

Comment: isn't the point of a MasterModel is to be extended by all other models instead of Eloquent's? You can have this in a base class and extend all other models from it

Comment: All my models are already extending MasterModel. MasterModel extends Eloquent's Model class.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators). The first approach. This requires the dates, to be defined in the `$dates` property. This will only be triggered if the Model is [serialized](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/55c9720bd28140938d6f4bd5f20fae868b0894d9/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L857).

```
public class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
}
```

You can also define [it](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization) in a provider in the boot method. Which will trigger when a Carbon date is serialized.

```
public function boot()
{
    Carbon::serializeUsing(function ($carbon) {
        return $carbon->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'd go about serializing the model, sorry.

Comment: How do you return you data usually or do you inject it to a view?

Comment: At the moment I'm doing a rough POC so I'm just returning raw arrays to the browser to print out the retrieved data