# Laravel eloquent added another anomaly string "T" and ".000000Z" to date

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-7

I dont know why, when I tried to call eloquent always get created_at and updated_at extra weird text. So `2020-07-25 10:05:25` it changed to `2020-07-25T10:05:25.000000Z`. Here is it my eloquent `Article::with('category')->get()->toJson()`, i want to keep updated_at and created_at as `2020-07-25 10:05:25`
.Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not weird text, it's a perfectly valid date in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You should be able to initialize a Carbon or DateTime object with it (if it isn't one already!) and call `format ` on it.

Comment: so what should i do in my eloquent or model to keep it `2020-07-25 10:05:25`? @CherryDT

Comment: I don't understand why you call this a problem. You are asking for a date and are getting a date. It would only be a problem if you wanted to format a date to something else in which case you need to format a date to a string which is a completely different question (and would require a use case and some code)

Comment: @apokryfos i have update my question. please help me

Comment: Take a look at `$dateFormat` at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions that may help you.

Comment: I have tried adding `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';` to my model but nothing happen @apokryfos

Comment: There's multiple ways you can achieve this. You can override `toJson` in your model, you can use attribute [accessors/mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators) you can also override the function `serializeDate` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074356/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-laravel-outputs-to-json/41569026#41569026). When you do try one (or all) of these and they don't work then do share what you tried and how it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my own problem with adding this to my model

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value){
    $date = Carbon::parse($value);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value){
    $date = Carbon::parse($value);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
```

Comment: `'Y-m-d H:m` *m* for month, you stored `H:m` **Hour:Month** it would be `'Y-m-d H:i:s` or `'Y-m-d H:i` **i** for **minute** and **s** for **seconds**

Answer (score 3):

### Just update at the model

```
use DateTimeInterface;
 
/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: If you've already have `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;` in your model then remove `use DateTimeInterface;` and replace `DateTimeInterface $date` to `$date` from the answer