# How to convert timestamp to unix timestamp in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, unix-timestamp, php-carbon

Hello great people of SO

I hope you all have a great day!

I have an issue with my project timestamps

I have 2 Models, `News` and `Comments`

During working on my project, I tried to replicate 'real world data'

So in my Seeder (`NewsSeeder`),

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use App\News;
...

public function run(Faker $faker) {
    News::create([
        'source' => $faker->url
        'body' => $faker->paragraphs(random_int(1, 4), true)
    ]):
}

// Please note that, relationship between `News` and `Comments` is `hasMany`
// `News` hasMany `Comment`
// `Comment` belongs to a `User`
```

In my `CommentSeeder`

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use App\News;
use App\Comment;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
...

public function run() {
    foreach (News::all() as $news) {
        $i = 0;
        for ($i; $i < random_int(1, 5); $i++) { // This will generate comments for each `News` with random amount
            $news->comments()->create([
                'user_id' => User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
                'body' => $faker->paragraphs(random_int(1,3), true),
                'created_at' => Carbon::parse($news->created_at)->addMinutes(random_int(1, 999)) // Comments created after the news is posted, make sense right?
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly like I want it to be

The problem is: **I see 2 timestamps format**

Example:

```
"news": [
    {
        "source": ...
        "body": ...
        "created_at": "2021-02-10 15:19:09" // This
        "comments": [
            {
                "user_id": ...
                "body": ...
                "created_at": "2021-02-10T16:22:33.000000Z" // and this
            },
            ...
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Q1:

Why they are different?

> In model I'm using `$table->timestamps();`, which is Laravel's default timestamps format

Q2:

How to make all my models timestamps become like this: "2021-02-10T08:22:33.000000Z"

Thanks in advance

If there's any unclear explanation, I will edit a.s.a.p

Comment: laravel by default send `unix timestamp` may be you modify somewhere  to other format

Comment: Hi, yes, I think I might have change it, In `CommentSeeder`, in this line: `Carbon::parse($news->created_at)->addMinutes(random_int(1, 999))`

Comment: Because you are using laravel 7 or earlier version  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63448356/4575350

Comment: How to make all my models timestamp become like comment model? like: `"2021-02-10T08:22:33.000000Z"`

Comment: Hi @sta, yes I'm using laravel ver. 7, how to change format to unix timestamp? idk much about php

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto you need to change it on your model, override the `serializeDate()` method

Comment: Show us the relevant part (eg timestamps) from the migrations for **both** News and Comments models.  And look in **both** models for relevant date/timestamp stuff, like any `$dates`, `$dateFormat`, `$casts`, etc.

Comment: Hi, @Don'tPanic, I don't change the default table timestamps, nor $casts attribute in model, everything comes with Laravel's default

Comment: @sta, `return $date-> ????;`

Comment: Interesting! *I see 2 timestamps format* - where/how do you see that?  I mean what code generates that dump, is it coming from DB?

Comment: @Don'tPanic **I guess** my `CommentSeeder`, in line: `created_at` might have changed it,

Comment: 2 timestamp are different, really weird. I am not sure where you need to change, on News or Comment model, may be on your Comment model

Comment: @sta how about using mutator? `public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value) {}` and change the format to unix timestamp, but **idk what Carbon function** to change it to unix timestamp

Comment: There is no Carbon function to change, here you assign a Carbon object to the comment date, and the output is good for comment. Here all the Carbon and comment stuff just make noise around your question which is: how to get "created_at": "2021-02-10T15:19:09.123456Z" instead of "created_at": "2021-02-10 15:19:09" in the "news" JSON output. And so we need the relevant part of the model and response to help. I suggest you to rewrite the question this way. But maybe at this point you'll find already asked similar questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54784868/2991319

Answer (score 0):

Add "->withTimestamps()" to your relation to add them.

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

In each model you want to change the format, add this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:{format}',
];
```

Replace the {format} with the format you want. I think it is "c" or something.